# Why my laptop gets stuck when working with Python list?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video file and all I want for now is put all the video's frames into a Python list. I am using Python's OpenCV library to do it. But my laptop could never do it. it just gets stuck and I have to cut the power to restart it. my guess is that python list is unable to handle all the frames due to memory deficiency. Here is the code and i believe it is the right way to do what I want(syntax).  now I need why the laptop is getting stuck and any solution other than using list.

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture("myvideo.mp4")
all_frames = []
while 1:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret:
        all_frames.append(frame)
        continue
    break
```

below is some data about the video that might help you
the video contains 7000 frames.
every frame has (1080, 1920) dimension

Comment: Why cant' you try pandas dataframe

Comment: You're putting no delay in your infinite loop...

Comment: @Niraj It'll still run out of memory

Comment: Probably a memory issue. Why are you reading an infinite amount of frames? Why aren'y you immediately doing something with them and releasing? Print a counter every iteration to see where you get "stuck", and know you're limits.

Comment: OP is stopping when `ret` is false. But 7000 frames of 1080x1920 24 bit uncompressed pixels makes around 40Gb if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: i dont have that pandas experience. can u show it to me? @NiranjRajasekaran

Comment: I think s/he's confusing the video frame with a Pandas frame - not the same thing.

Comment: i know it is insane @Jean-FrançoisFabre but i need any other method of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't afford to do that this way.

When reading, the frames are *uncompressed* from the `.mp4` to *raw* output like 3 bytes per pixel or such.

So you want to store 7000*3*1080*1920 bytes total which is roughly 43 Gb !!

Not to mention that the constant resizing of the list owing to `append` creates even more copies, so even *if* you had the memory available, this would be very long.

The idea behind this program is probably to analyse the frames. So basically you don't need *all* the frames in memory at the same time.

In that case, read a small number of them (in a revolving buffer), perform your shape detection analysis, whatever, store the analysed data (much smaller) and drop the raw data, repeat (programs performing real-time analysis cannot store *all* the data, because they're running forever)